# Как объяснить, что Angular проект на Safari лагает, а на Chome летает?

Tags: angular, safari

Проект отлично работает в браузере Chrome, но лагает при скроллинге и при наведении мыши в сафари очень сильно.
Код написан без говнокода, вариант, что проц Silicon M1Pro Max 64Gb не тянет - исключён, но сайт в сафари лагает не по детски.
В чём может быть дело?
Какие полифилы или ещё что-то нужно, что б сайт работал?
Спасибо.

Comment: Вроде как [была такая проблема](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6350), связанная с тем, как Safari использует CPU и GPU для отрисовки. Возможно для скроллящихся элементов стоит добавить `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` чтобы задействовать GPU. А для оптимизации наведения можно использовать `debounce` в виде дополнительного декоратора к `@HostListener`, как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634992/debounce-hostlistener-event), чтобы не так часто триггерить ченж детектор, особенно когда быстро проезжаешь мышкой при скролле над компонентами с хост лиснером типа `mouseenter`.

Comment: Вероятно, стоит еще добавить OnPush стратегию, ну и как сказали выше, посмотреть на листенеры. Без кода сложно сказать, где есть утечка или перерасход памяти или процессора.